# How to resolve GraphQl mutations that have an array as the input

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, prisma-graphql

So am new to GraphQL and I'm trying to resolve a mutation that has an Input type of an array. I'm getting this error

```
{
  "data": {
    "createSub": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable '$data' expected value of type 'SubCreateInput!' but got: {\"apps\":[{\"name\":\"ma\",\"package\":\"me\",\"running\":true,\"isSysytem\":true}]}. Reason: 'apps' Expected 'AppListCreateManyInput', found not an object. (line 1, column 11):\nmutation ($data: SubCreateInput!) {\n          ^",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createSub"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my schema

```
type Mutation {
    createSub(input:subInput): Sub  
  }

input subInput{

    apps: [AppListInput]
}

type Sub{
    id: ID!
    apps: [AppList]  
  }


type AppList {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    package: String
    running: Boolean
    isSysytem: Boolean

}

input AppListInput {
    name: String
    package: String
    running: Boolean
    isSysytem: Boolean

  }
```

And this is my resolver

```
function createSub(root, args, context) {
    return context.prisma.createSub({
      apps: args.input.apps
    })
  }
```

The mutation/payload am sending on the Graphql playground is this

```
mutation{
    createSub( input:{
      apps: [{
        name: "ma"
        package: "me"
        running: true
        isSysytem: true

      }],
    })
  {
    apps{
      name
    }
  }
  }
```

When I *console.log(args.input.apps)* I'm getting this

```
[ [Object: null prototype] { name: 'ma', package: 'me', running: true, isSysytem: true } ]
```

This is the input *AppListCreateManyInput* generated in the schema

```
input AppListCreateManyInput {
  create: [AppListCreateInput!]
  connect: [AppListWhereUniqueInput!]
}
```

What could I be missing please?

Comment: Refresh the playground in the browser, or try recompiling your typings. It looks like they're out of date with what you have supplied here. `Reason: 'apps' Expected 'AppListCreateManyInput',` the type `AppListCreateManyInput` isn't part of what you've supplied, and the query isn't part of the code example either. ( for example:   `$data' expected value of type 'SubCreateInput` the mutation `SubCreateInput`, and variable name `data`  are not part of your example code ) Otherwise, from what I'm seeing it looks like your code example is on the right track.

Comment: @jmunsch I have tried recompiling my types severally. I have even created a new database instance and rewrote my models afresh but the error persists.

Comment: @jmunsch And as for types/inputs like *AppListCreateManyInput*  and *SubCreateInput*  those are generated in the schema by Prisma

Comment: The `apps` you're passing in should be an object, not an array, as indicated by the error. Take a look at the definition for `AppListCreateManyInput` inside your generated schema file to see what shape that object should be. Update your question with the definition from the schema file if you're still unsure.

Comment: @DanielRearden I'm getting the same error even after passing in *apps* as an object. I have updated the question to include the *AppListCreateManyInput* from the schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the appropriate object to `createSub`, as shown [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/writing-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc6/#nested-object-writes). Because `apps` is a relation, you can't just pass an array of `apps` in -- after all, when creating the `Sub`, you may want to either create new apps and relate them to the newly created Sub, or simply relate existing apps to it.

```
return context.prisma.createSub({
  apps: {
    create: args.input.apps, // create takes an array of apps to create
  }
})
```

If you wanted to connect existing apps instead of creating new ones, you would use `connect` instead of `create` and pass in an object specifying a where condition instead of an array.